# Assembly.LoadFrom works, Assembly.Load does not

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I am trying to load the file using `Assembly.Load` but I get a BadImageException, but if I try and load the exact same assembly using `Assembly.LoadFrom` it works.

```cs
// this works.
var asm1 = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);

// this throws an exception
var ba = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
var asm2 = Assembly.Load(ba);
```

As you can see from the code above, the assembly is exactly the same, but it works for `Assembly.LoadFrom` but not `Assembly.Load`

What could be the reason for it? How can I get `Assembly.Load` to work?

Comment: It is probably a mixed-mode assembly, also containing unmanaged code.  Disk file required.

Comment: Yes, it is a managed c++ assembly, but why does it work for `Assembly.LoadFrom` but not `Assembly.Load`? Shall I copy the bytes to the temp folder? or is there a prefered directory to copy the assembly?

Comment: You are hiding too much info.  These bytes were written to a file when the assembly was created.  They better stay in that file while it travels to your user's machine.  You can't win the battle against the user's security software.

Answer (score 3):

[`Assmebly.Load`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_Assembly_Load_System_Byte___) might throw `BadImageException`  while reflecting on C++ executable files might, unlike [`Assembly.LoadFrom(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_Assembly_LoadFrom_System_String_).
For fixing that issue you have to use `/fixed:no` while linking.
Here is the paragraph from Msdn:

> Reflecting on C++ executable files might throw a
>   BadImageFormatException. This is most likely caused by the C++
>   compiler stripping the relocation addresses or the .reloc section from
>   your executable file. To preserve the .reloc address for your C++
>   executable file, specify /fixed:no when you are linking.

Comment: Copy/pasting the docs is not that useful.  Nobody creates C++/CLI assemblies anymore that can be linked with /fixed:no

Comment: @HansPassant, why do you say "Nobody creates C++/CLI assemblies anymore that can be linked with /fixed:no", what is so wrong with that setting?
I am not saying I will do it, I am just curious about your statement.

Comment: @Farhad Jabiyev, I am using a managed c++ assembly and by default it has `FIXED:NO`, (VS2019)

Comment: @SimonGoodman Have you checked to store read byte array to the new file and call Assembly.LoadFrom?